# How does vpn help bypassing blocked site?

Tags: networking, vpn

I am a software developer with a non networking background.

I am trying to understand how vpn works. I think I have a high level understanding of how vpn works internally, i.e. tunneling, end-user's ip address getting hidden, vpn server making request on behalf of end user which helps with geo location blocking etc.

I am not understanding the "vpn helps with accessing bocked content" part. Say I am in a university, and my university has facebook and youtube blocked. How will I access these websites using vpn.

I am trying to understand vpn at ip packets level. If I type facebook.com in my university's address, how will vpn help be access this site, which would have been inaccessible otherwise,

Answer (score 1):

VPN does 2 things.

It tunnels all data through the VPN on a secure line. You connect to that VPN, and once connected, all data is encrypted between you and the VPN server.

The university will see that you connect to a VPN, but can't see what traffic goes over that line, so they cannot block the data.

Websites may block certain countries. They do this by blocking ip ranges. When you connect through a VPN, it is the ip address of the vpn that the website now sees, not your own public ip address. This means they now need to actively block that vpn's ip address in order to block you. Given there are so many different VPN services out there, and new ones come and go every so many days, it is nearly impossible to keep up with adding these ip addresses, so aside of global country ip bans, they can't or wont restrict based on other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is *just slightly* wrong but in a critical way. The VPN does not make requests on behalf of the end user.

A VPN creates a "virtual" Internet connection across your actual one, encrypting the data. Data originates from the VPN IP address assigned to your end of the connection (ehich the University does not get to see/know) and all the University sees is encrypted traffic between the vpn endpoints.